# Python: Natural Language Processing (NLP)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a billion strings in a HiveQL database. I am loading them into Python. The strings are not space-delimited, and look like:

```
"mynameisanon"
...
"helloworld"
```

I would like to count the number of words in every string. But first, I'd need a dictionary. I don't know how to get a dictionary of words, but suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
{ hello, world, my, name, is}
```

Then the function would work like:

```
Input:  mynameisanon
Output: 3

Input:  helloworld
Output: 2
```

In the end, I would like a Pandas table.

Comment: This is going to be impossible to do. For example, 'CANNOTEAT' - contains 'can, not, eat', OR 'cannot, eat', OR, 'can, note, at'. So is is two words or three? And if three, which three?

Comment: Possible dictionary source: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

Comment: @Alex that is a very good point. In such a scenario, I would take the max number of words counted, so it would be 3. I do not care what words it contains, I am just interested in the max word count. I just wonder if I can implement a solution that can handle the scale of a large library (perhaps intelligently subset to words that have characters above a certain threshold and less than the length of the string).

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you, that is very helpful. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, this cannot be done uniquely, in the general case, but assuming a dictionary that accounts for that:

(Not particularly well tested):

```
strings = ["mynameisanon", "helloworld"]

words = ["hello", "world", "my", "name", "is"]

for string in strings:
    count = 0
    max_interval = len(string)
    for interval_length in range(1,max_interval+1):
        for interval_start in range(0, len(string)+1-interval_length):
            interval = string[interval_start:(interval_start+interval_length)]
            if interval in words:
                count += 1
    print(string)
    print(count)
```

This assumes words can be as small as one letter, and as long as the whole string, and checks for words of all lengths between those values